# matlab Create growing matrix with for loop that grows by 3 per loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

So I have written this:

```
HSRXdistpR = squeeze(comDatape_m1(2,7,1,:,isubj));
HSRXdistpL = squeeze(comDatape_m1(2,4,1,:,isubj));
TocomXdistp = squeeze(comDatape_m1(2,10,1,:,isubj));

for i = 1:2;
     HSRXp = NaN(8,3*i);
     HSRXp(:,i*3) = [HSRXdistpR(:,i) HSRXdistpL(:,i) TocomXdistp(:,i)];
end
```

In the first part I am just selecting data from a 5-D matrix, nothing special. All that's important here is that it creates an 8x2 matrix per line (isubj=2). Now I want to add the first column of each matrix into an 8x3 matrix, and then the second column of each matrix into the same matrix (creating an 8x6 matrix). Since the number of my subjects will vary, I want to do this in a for loop. This way, if the isubj increases to 3, it should go on to create an 8x9 matrix.

So I tried to create a matrix that will grow by 3 for each iteration of i, which selects the ith column of each of the 3 matrices and then puts them in there.

However I get the following error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

Is it possible to let a matrix grow by more than one in a for loop? Or how should it be done otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
HSRXp(:,i*3) = [HSRXdistpR(:,i) HSRXdistpL(:,i) TocomXdistp(:,i)];
```

You're trying to assign an n x 3 matrix (RHS) into an n x 1 vector (LHS). It would be easier to simply use horizontal concatenation:

```
HSRXp = [HSRXp, [HSRXdistpR(:,i) HSRXdistpL(:,i) TocomXdistp(:,i)]];
```

But that would mean reallocation at each step, which might slow your code down if the matrix becomes large.

Comment: This is most definitely much better then I had at first, there is still one strange thing that pops up though. First let me show you my code as is:

`HSRXp = NaN(8,1);

for i = 1:2;
      HSRXp = [HSRXp, [HSRXdistpR(:,i) HSRXdistpL(:,i) TocomXdistp(:,i)]];
end `

But now HSRXp becomes a nx7 matrix instead of nx6, with a NaN column as it's first column. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Whoops! I'm dumb. I think I know what is happening there :')

Comment: Happens to the best of us.